# Python: file-object conflicts

Tags: python, file

I'm beginning with python and I created a class of file-object deriving from the 'file' class to be able to manipulate large datafiles.
I have created specific methods to work on these files that are built like shown below.
I need to return a new instance of MyClass after each method to be able to keep working on them. The problem is that when I use several time the same method there are conflict with the file foo.txt that is used as a temporary file because it is still used as the support of MyClass instance.
Is there a way around this ? Or do I need to create randomized names for all my files ?

Thanks for your answers,
George

```
Class MyClass(file):
    "Similar to open(file_path,'r')"
    def __init__(self,file_path):
        file.__init__(self,file_path)
    self.tell()

    def method(self):
        """Extract informations from self to write them in a temporary file foo.txt
        that will be used to return a new instance of MyClass"""
        output=open('foo.txt','w')
        self.seek(0)
        # Extracting information from self 
        output.write(information)
        output.close()
        return MyClass('foo.txt')
```

I have completed the exemple to make it more clear. I think that my problem is that I am returning a new instance of MyClass from a file I create in the method. If I use the method several times without closing the instances generated from foo.txt, the instances become empty and return 'None' because foo.txt is re-written. For exemple:

```
a=MyClass('/path/to/file')
b=a.method()
c=b.method()
```

Then returns an error because b is empty

Comment: I get the feeling you're looking for the [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) module to create temporary files for you. But from your question it's not clear where `file_path` and `'foo.txt'` are coming from / what they stand for.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think that temporary files wouldn't solve my problem. Is it possible in Pyton to create a file-object from scratch (without a file) or to make a file-object independent from the file supporting it ?

Comment: Why do you need a new instance every time you execute `method`? In this way you have to solve several additional problems as file access sync, closing the temp file etc...

Comment: I'd like to return a new instance each time 'method' is applied so I can apply other methods to the resulting file-object.

Comment: you're doing an unnecessary subclassing, when a simple encapsulation can work ; and remember that explicit is better than implicit. Don't chain methods just for the sake of chaining methods, it's not javascript here, it's python, so be [zen](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, your diagnostic is right, and your problem is that your use case is wrong. If you do want to do what it looks like you want, here's how it should work:

```
a=MyClass('/path/to/file')
a.method('/path/to/foo.txt')
b=MyClass('/path/to/foo.txt')
b.method('/path/to/bar.txt')
c=MyClass('/path/to/bar.txt')
```

which is simple and will work well (of course, I won't give the details of how you give the argument to `open()`). Though, it lacks elegancy.

To improve on that, you may want to create unique temporary files, which will enable you to do what you want:

```
a=MyClass('/path/to/file')
b=a.method()
c=b.method()
```

but the problem is that you still don't handle correctly the newly created/opened temporary files. So, you'd better use context manager:

```
with open('/path/to/file') as a:
    with MyClass(a).method() as b:
        with MyClass(b).method() as c:
            # use a, b and c files here
            pass
# and now, a is closed, b and c are deleted.
```

so you close the files when you don't need them anymore:

```
import tempfile

Class MyClass():
    def __init__(self,file):
        self.file = file

    def method(self):
        """Extract informations from self to write them in a temporary file foo.txt
        that will be used to return a new instance of MyClass"""
        output = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        self.seek(0)
        # Extracting information from self 
        output.write(information)
        return output
```

of course, that's one way of doing it, you may work it out in many other ways. The beauty of this solution is that your [temporary file gets deleted when you `close()` is called](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile), which happens when you exit the context of the file.

Of course, there are other ways to implement this, but I find this is the most simple and explicit way to work it out (given you give an explicit name to `method()` of course).

HTH

Comment: +1 for not returning a new instance of `MyClass` in `method`, and for being a good and helpful answer of course :)

Comment: well, @danodonovan, you're right, and I tend to forget to say the obvious: in good OOP, the only acceptable occasion you return a new instance of current class from a method, is from a class method aka static method, in order to implement a factory pattern, otherwise your design is wrong! ;-)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer. The objects are a bit more complicated to handle like this since I need to create a new instance myself before applying a method, but it might be more "pythonic" this way.
However to make your solution work fine I need to add a line `file.seek(0)` in the constructor, otherwise it's creating an empty object :)

Comment: no, it's not *needed*, though you'll only loose a few cycles doing so. `self.file.seek(0)` is needed only before you want to read from it, in case you need to read twice from `file`, so it only has to be in `.method()`. And about `.method()` not returning an instance, it's not only about being more pythonic, but about making code that someone can understand. When you code always have in mind that someone else may read your code… And that someone may be **you** in six months.